# wait, notify in java ExecutorService if future work not define previously?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice

How to apply wait, notify to java `ExecutorService` after declaring thread pool as

```java
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
```

The future work no define previously

Comment: Why do you need wait/notify if you have an ExecutorService?

Comment: to currently stop the sending jobs to worker theareds

Comment: The `wait` and `notify` would work as having 10 threads. However, if you have an `ExecutorService`, it should be a lot easier to have  an event dispatcher.

Comment: I suppose you meant throttling job submittion. You could use Guava RateLimiter or Semaphore. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19819837/java-executor-with-throttling-throughput-control

Comment: To stop accepting new jobs you can use ExecutorService.shutdown() or shutdownNow().

Comment: Yes. but how can i start the service from previous point?