# API rate limiting with Completablefuture for async processing

Tags: java, multithreading, future, executorservice

I am trying to handle the API rate limiting. I found that using `ratelimiter` I can block the usage of resources. Hence, in the following code I am trying to have only two threads until the batch (`size`) is completed processing.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.RateLimiter;

public class thenapply {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
        final AtomicInteger sum = new AtomicInteger(0);
        final RateLimiter rateLimiter = RateLimiter.create(2.0); // rate is "2 permits per second"
        int size = list.size();
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(size);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            final int finali = i;
            rateLimiter.acquire(); // should wait till I get 2 requests
            CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
                int sq= newdoc(list.get(finali));
                sum.addAndGet(sq);
                latch.countDown();
            });
        }
        latch.await();
        System.out.println(sum);
    }

    public static int newdoc(int val){
        return val*val;
    }
}
```

1. In real time when we are trying to use the service, the end-user will be trying to call the service and if he calls it multiple times, we are throwing some error. How can we handle that using the `delay`. So basically, currently I have two requests using `ratelimiter` after that no request will be handled. how can I queue them with a `delay`?
2. When will `ratelimiter.acquire()` be free to give resources? If after the processing of two requests, then what about my `latch.countDown` as it is after the `for` loop?

Comment: If you want to have two threads, then `RateLimiter` is the wrong tool -- you need an `Executor` with the right number of threads.

Comment: @LouisWasserman can you please give an example of the solution? I am saying based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19819837/java-executor-with-throttling-throughput-control

Comment: `Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2); CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> { ... }, executor);`

Comment: thanks @LouisWasserman. I am reading the threadpool. will this block 3rd request until the entire thread pool is free i.e. until request 1 and request 2 are completed? What if we want to send the 3rd request directly after the request 1 finishes even if request 2 is still running?

Comment: It will run request 3 as soon as either one finishes.

Comment: Thanks @LouisWasserman. I think that the above code doesn't guarantee us that there will be two request/second, right? If not how about using,

`Executor delayed = CompletableFuture.delayedExecutor(0.5L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {......}, delayed)`

This will assure every request gets sent after 0.5s.How does that sound?

Comment: Do you care about two requests per second, or two requests at a time?  If the first one, RateLimiter.  If the second one, Executor.